# Need to create ReadStream API with different endpoints in NodeJs. Preprocessing and giving cached result is better or reading file at every api call?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have to create an API to read file as an input and provide endpoints with differnt queries like total word count, frequency of words etc.

Which is the better approach :

1. Preprossing the file at the beginning and then just give result from cached data.
2. Read file everytime when user queries any endpoint.

Comment: Does the file ever change?  Is it always the same file or how many different files does this apply to?  How large is the file?  How many possible different queries are there?  How many queries per minute will  you be processing?

Comment: My general rule for architecture decisions like this is to stay with the simplest implementation possible until I had proven and hard evidence that I needed to write more complex code.  That rule would advise to start with #2 and only go to the more involved implementation of #1 when you had proof of a performance problem and understood the profile or queries that you were receiving and thus could architect the most relevant solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 No the file does not changes and text file can range from few mbs to 1-2 gbs.

Comment: Start with #2 (the simpler option) and see how that goes.